# Update a mongo field based on another collections data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I'm looking for a way to update a field based on the sum of the data of another collection.

I tried to bring all the meals and use forEach to call the Products collection for each meal, tested if it was working, but I got a time out.

```
meals.find().forEach(meal => {
    var products = db.Products.find(
        { sku: { $in: meal.products } },
        { _id: 1, name: 1, sku: 1, nutritional_facts: 1 }
    )
    printjson(products)
})
```

My goal was to execute something like this below to get the desired result, but I got "SyntaxError: invalid for/in left-hand side". Is not possible to use for in inside a mongo query?

```
db.Meals.find({}).forEach(meal => {

    const nutri_facts = {};

    db.Products.find({ sku: { $in: meal.products } }, 
    { _id: 1, name: 1, sku: 1, nutri_facts: 1 }).forEach(product => {
        for (let nutriFact in product.nutri_facts) {
            nutri_facts[nutriFact] =
                    parseFloat(nutri_facts[nutriFact]) +
                    parseFloat(product.nutri_facts[nutriFact]);
            }
        }
    });

    for (let nutriFact in nutri_facts) {
            meal.nutri_facts[nutriFact] = 
            nutri_facts[nutriFact];
        }
    }

    db.Meals.updateOne({ _id: meal._id }, meal)
});
```

I also had a hard time trying to figure out how to use aggregate and lookup in this case but was not successful.

Is it possible to do that?

Example - Meals Document

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
   products : ["P068","L021","L026"], //these SKUs are part of this meal
   nutri_facts: {
    total_fat: 5g,
    calories: 100kcal
    (...other properties)
   }
}
```

For each meal I need to look for its products on 'Products' collections using 'sku' field. 
Then I will sum the nutritional facts of all products to get the meal nutritional facts.

Example Products Document

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
   sku: 'A010'
   nutri_facts: {
    total_fat: 2g,
    calories: 40kcal
    (...other properties)
   }
}
```

I know that mongo might not be the best option in this case, but the entire application is already built using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For each meal I need to look for its products on 'Products'
>   collections using 'sku' field. Then I will sum the nutritional facts
>   of all products to get the meal nutritional facts.

```
db.Meals.find( { } ).forEach( meal => {

    // print(meal._id);
    const nutri_facts_var = { };

    db.Products.find( { sku: { $in: meal.products } }, { nutri_facts: 1 }.forEach( product => {

         // printjson(product.nutri_facts);

        for ( let nutriFact in product.nutri_facts ) {

            let units = (product.nutri_facts[nutriFact].split(/\d+/)).pop();
            // print(units)

            // Checks for the existence of the field and then adds or assigns
            if ( nutri_facts_var[nutriFact] ) {
                nutri_facts_var[nutriFact] = parseFloat( nutri_facts_var[nutriFact] ) + parseFloat( product.nutri_facts[nutriFact] );
            }
            else {
                nutri_facts_var[nutriFact] = parseFloat( product.nutri_facts[nutriFact] );
            }

            nutri_facts_var[nutriFact] = nutri_facts_var[nutriFact] + units;
        }

    } );

   // printjson(nutri_facts_var);

   db.Meals.updateOne( { _id: meal._id }, { $set: { nutri_facts: nutri_facts_var } } );
} );
```

**NOTES:**

1. I use the variable `nutri_facts_var` name ( the `var` suffixed) so
   that we can distinguish the user defined variable names easily from
   the document fields names.
2. { _id: 1, name: 1, sku: 1, nutri_facts: 1 } changed to {
   nutri_facts: 1 }. The `_id` is *included* by default in a
   projection. The fields `name` and `sku` are not needed.
3. `db.Meals.updateOne({ _id: meal._id }, meal)` is not a correct
   syntax. The update operations use [Update
   Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/).
   The corrected code: `db.Meals.updateOne( { _id: meal._id }, { $set:
   { nutri_facts: nutri_facts_v  } } )`. Note we are updating the
   nutifacts only, not all details.
4. Since the individual nutrifacts are stored as strings (e.g.,
   "100kcal"), during arithmetic the string parts are stripped. So, we
   capture the string *units* (e.g., "kcal") for each nutrifact and
   append it later after the arithmetic. The following code strips and
   stores the *units* part: `let units =
   (product.nutri_facts[nutriFact].split(/\d+/)).pop()`.
5. Use the *mongo shell* methods `print` and `printjson` to print the
   contents of a variable or an object respectively - for debugging
   purposes.

Note the query updates the `Meal` collection even if the `nutri_facts` field is not defined in it; the `$set` update operator creates new fields and sets the values in case the fields do not exist.

Comment: Thanks!! My problem, in this case, is that I have a lot of attributes inside nutri_facts, so I believe it would be better to use a loop, but it is not working. Do you know if itś possible? I updated the question considering the query I built using a for/in.

Comment: I made changes to the code. Study the notes and code to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It was very helpful!